# Local Drupal site installation failure

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, acquia

I am trying to import a local drupal site from a git repository.

I am using Acquia Dev Desktop2.

I keep getting this error and I was hoping if anyone has experienced this before and has a solution:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a database issue. Are you importing a database? Check your settings.php file and ensure that they point to a valid database, then, if you don't need to have any data to start with I would suggest ensuring that the database is empty (no tables) and then do a site install via the UI or whatever.

If you are intending to import a database then it looks like the database you've got is corrupt or incomplete.

Comment: I am importing a database.  I've also tried it where I did a clean install and imported the tables into the new database. I actually get a different error with that.  Thanks for the reply.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Database corrupt? If the site works on a clean install but breaks when you import a database, it points to perhaps an incomplete or corrupt database. I've had the exact thing before and resolved it by getting a fresh dump.